# Deploying EAR-File to Wildfly-8.0.0.Final fails with missing/unsatisfied dependencies

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, java-ee-5, wildfly

I have an EAR-File with the following structure:

`/
|- lib/
|- lib/tons-of.jar
|- client-version-check.jar
|- config-ejb.jar
|- cw2.war
|- software-version-registry-xml.jar
|- ... (tons of other war/jar files)`

While trying to deploy this on WildFly (using WildFly-8.0.0.Final with `standalone-full.xml`) I get the following errors:

```
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."project-ear-4.0.0-SNAPSHOT-mssql-2005.ear"."client-version-check.jar".deploymentCompleteService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."project-ear-4.0.0-SNAPSHOT-mssql-2005.ear"."software-version-registry-xml.jar".INSTALL, service jboss.deployment.unit."project-ear-4.0.0-SNAPSHOT-mssql-2005.ear".deploymentCompleteService] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."project-ear-4.0.0-SNAPSHOT-mssql-2005.ear"."config-ejb.jar".component.CenterwareConfigBean.VIEW."centerware.config.CenterwareConfig".LOCAL (missing) dependents: [service jboss.naming.context.java.module."project-ear-4.0.0-SNAPSHOT-mssql-2005".cw2-war.env."centerware.servlets.FileUploadServlet".centerwareConfig] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."project-ear-4.0.0-SNAPSHOT-mssql-2005.ear"."config-ejb.jar".component.CenterwareKeyValue.VIEW."centerware.config.CenterwareKeyValue".LOCAL (missing) dependents: [service jboss.naming.context.java.module."project-ear-4.0.0-SNAPSHOT-mssql-2005".cw2-war.env.CenterwareKeyValue]
```

My `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` includes `<ear-subdeployments-isolated>true</ear-subdeployments-isolated>`.

Unluckily I have no idea what goes wrong and how to avoid/remove this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem was caused in my `ear/META-INF/application.xml`, where `<initialize-in-order>true</initialize-in-order>` was set. Since my application.xml is created by `maven-ear-plugin`, the list is in alphabetical order and so was processed in alphabetical order, which does not work for my application.